# Dynamic Grid CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

How do I achieve a dynamic grid that looks like this ? :

[image]

I cannot figure out how to properly construct the css to achieve this. Currently, this is what my grid looks like:

[image]

Here's a fiddle where I have been trying to solve this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqeo9ety/2/

---

Here's my current css:

```
blue {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.red {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks a ton for any ideas!!

Comment: are you using `gridster.js` ?

Comment: Try using [Gridster.JS](http://gridster.net/). Check the [Demo](http://gridster.net/demos/dynamic-grid-width.html)

Comment: Thanks @Joker. What if i don't want the drag and drop functionality?

Comment: @bluet thanks but I need to be able to order the items horizontally. The client wants to order them in the backend, and that order needs to be reflected in the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it while preserving the semantic order:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/jw68xs6o/1/)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="blue">1</div>
<div class="blue">2</div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue b3">3</div>
<div class="blue b4">4</div>
<div class="blue b5">5</div>
<div class="blue b6">6</div>
<div class="blue b7">7</div>
<div class="blue">8</div>
<div class="blue">9</div>
<div class="blue">10</div>
<div class="blue">11</div>
</div>

.blue {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.b3, .b6 {
    float: right;
}

.b4, .b7 {
    clear: both;
}

.red {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    left: 110px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}

#container {
    width: 250px;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
<div id="container">

<div id="c1">
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>

<div id="c2">    
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>

<div id="c3">
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

With the following additional CSS:

```
#c1, #c2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

The main idea being setting it up in three columns first.

Comment: Only problem is that I need it to be ordered horizontally since it is dynamic and controlled through a backend. The user wants to be able to sort the blue items independently of the red item.

Comment: A div 2 blue boxes in height that contains the 3-column layout above, followed by a div that spans the whole page to pick up the last row of blues?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how the user is going to be able to order a list of blue items on the backend and have that order reflected in the frontend unless the semantic order is preserved.. Am i mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

`Gridster` is a `jQuery` plugin that allows building intuitive `draggable` layouts from elements spanning multiple columns. Try using [GridsterJS](http://gridster.net/). Live [Demos](http://gridster.net/#demos).

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){ //DOM Ready

    $(".gridster ul").gridster({
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
    });

});
```

And that's it. It starts working. All you have to do is to set properties according to your needs to enable/disable its features in this function.

You can enable/disable drag and drop functionality by using,

```
// Disables drag and drop
$(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster').disable()

// Enables drag and drop
$(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster').enable()
```